# How to check ip-port mapping after adding a port-forwarding rule by firewall-cmd

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

In CentOS7, I have made a tcp relay by command "firewall-cmd --add-forward-ports ...".
However, now I need to know the mapping rules between incoming ip and the port assigned to the ip by NAT as the new source port.

Is there a translation table somewhere in my system or how can I get the in-time-mapping?
Now the only possible way I have thought out is to add some LOG rule in iptables where a forwarding is accepted.

Comment: You seem to be aware of *iptables*, so I am unsure whether this helps: In Centos 7, *firewall-cmd* is just a front-end to the *iptables* command (Centos 8 might use *nftables* instead, I am not sure). To *see* the rules, run `iptables -S -t nat` or replace `-S` by `-L`. To see the entirety of all rules, not only NAT: `iptables-save`. To *understand* the rules, use `man iptables` or find a tutorial.

Comment: @berndbausch Thanks for comment. But what I want to know is not the iptables rules but the NAT mapping. For example, one incoming package with source address ip1:port1 and destination address ip2:port2 triggers my forward rule, and its source address would be rewritten  as ip2:port3 and its destination address would also be rewritten as my iptables rule defines. What I want to know is port3.

Comment: Hmmm. As far as I understand it, the mapping is defined by netfilter rules. I don't think there is anything different that you can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer myself after carefully inspecting the package addresses.
The answer is quite simple: the new source port is exactly the same as the original source port.
For example, the source and destination address of original package is **ip1:port1** and **ip2:port2**, and according my forwarding rule the destination address of the new package is **ip3:port2**, then the source address of the new package would be **ip2:port1**.